# Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

**error**

```
Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: 0
```

**html**

**Activator** (a menu item) of the `getConcessionaireList` function.

```
<ion-item ng-click="getConcessionaireList()" >
</ion-item>
```

**Input search** for the lists of displayed data from `$scope.concessionairesList`

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchQuery">
<ion-list>
```

**Values** from `$scope.concessioniresList` is to be displayed here when **Activator** is clicked.

```
<ion-item class="item item-icon-left" ng-repeat="x in concessionairesList track by $index | filter:searchQuery" href="#/app/encodereading/{{x.accountNumber}}">
    {{x.accountNumber}} - {{x.meterNumber}} - {{x.lastName | capitalize}}, {{x.firstName | capitalize}} {{x.middleName | initial}}
</ion-item>
```

**js**

**Data** that will be fetched from database using `php`

```
$scope.getConcessionaireList = function(){
      $http.get('http://localhost/test/php/getConcessionaires.php').then(function(res){
        $scope.show($ionicLoading);
        console.log(res.data);
        $scope.concessionairesList = res.data;
      }).finally(function(){
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.hide($ionicLoading);
        }, 1000)
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using **`track by $index`** before you are applying your filter. To resolve this, change your expression to:

```
<ion-item class="item item-icon-left" ng-repeat="x in concessionairesList  | filter:searchQuery track by $index" href="#/app/encodereading/{{x.accountNumber}}">
```

Comment: i will accept your answer a little bit. there is an time interval for posting and accepting an answer.

Comment: Now you should be able to